# Jenkins build failing on namespaced class not found (but phpunit works from command line)

Tags: wordpress, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a WP project with structure:

```
public_html/ // wp-project stuff like wp-config, etc)
tests/       // phpunit test classes
```

When running in bash shell:
`$phpunit /tests`
all the the tests pass just fine

But Jenkins is failing on on one of the plugins classes (which is namespaced) not found.

Not sure why this is happening (or how to fix) ?